# Crystal Report Engine Exception .net

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am working on an asp.net application. I migrated to a new term-server and running the crystal report throwing the following error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor()
```

I tried downloading and installing [SAP Crystal Report Runtime engine](https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html) on the term-server and the report does not show. I am able to see the report on the old term-server and dev server, but I am unable to get the report to run on the new term-server.

I downloaded and installed both the 32-bit and 64-bit.

Am I installing the correct thing? What else should I try?

[image]